# Laravel FileNotFoundException thrown even though file exists

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I ran into a problem today to which I can't seem to find a solution.

I'm creating a class for image upload. The upload itself works fine, but when I try to use the uploaded file for creating a thumbnail, for some reason the file can't be found.

My code:

```
private static $imageTypes = [
    "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif", "image/x-ms-bmp"
];

public function upload(UploadedFile $file, $folder = 'common')
{
    if (!$this->isImage($file)) {
        return false;
    }

    $path = $this->createPath($file, $folder);

    try {
        $file->move($path, $file->getClientOriginalName());
        $filePath = sprintf("%s/%s", $path, $file->getClientOriginalName());
    } catch (FileException $e) {
        return false;
    }

    $realPath = 'public/' . $filePath;
    //dd(File::exists($realPath)); - this returns false
    //dd(File::get($realPath)); - this throws the exception
    $image = Image::make(File::get($realPath));

    // Code for creating a thumbnail - not implemented yet.
    $thumbnailPath = '';

    return [
        'image' => $path,
        'thumbnail' => $thumbnailPath
    ];
}

private function isImage(UploadedFile $file)
{
    $type = $file->getClientMimeType();

    return in_array($type, self::$imageTypes);
}

private function createPath(UploadedFile $file, $folder)
{
    $time = Carbon::now();

    $path = sprintf(
        'Code/images/uploads/%s/%d-%d',
        $folder,
        $time->year,
        $time->month
    );

    return $path;
}
```

I know the file gets uploaded, but I have no idea why it can't be found. I've tried the same action using `php artisan tinker` and it works there, so the problem is not in the file path.

The only idea that I've come up so far is that is related to directory permissions, but I haven't been able to verify it yet.

Comment: Btw, Why can't you verify file permission?

Comment: Well, that was the idea I came up at the time of writing this question. I just checked and the permissions are not the reason why this doesn't work. I'm completely out of ideas now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe your problem is here: `$realPath = 'public/' . $filePath;`. You need full path to your upload folder, so try replacing it with `public_path()."/".$filePath`.

Comment: Thanks, it fixed the problem. It's always the simplest things... I'm still surprised that it worked in console without problems.

Comment: That's actually quite a common mistake. And the reason it worked from console is that CLI php scripts treat paths differently.

Answer (score 4):

I have fallen in the same situation recently, so here is a hint

Laravel after version 5 seems to allow dealing with files (get/put) only when using declared storage defined into filesystems.php

In that case the user must use 'local' or 'public' storage for getting the image or file stored.
According to the code above, please do the following

1. edit *config/filesystems.php* find local and make the following change

```
'local' => [
   'driver' => 'local',
   'root' => storage_path('app/local/common'),
],
```

2. In order to read the file (ie 'image1.jpg') (get)

```
$afile = storage::disk('public')->get('image1.jpg');
```

In your case:

```
$realpath =  'image1.jpg'; //**Just the filename**
$image = Image::make(storage::disk('local')->get($realPath));
```

Hope this helps